# Ms Access: VBA combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I use the following VBA Code for combo boxes in MS Access Form

```
Private Sub ComboEmployee_AfterUpdate()
Dim myFilter As String
myFilter = "Select * from Filter_Employee where ([LastName] = iif('" & ComboEmployee & "'='(All)',[LastName],'" & ComboEmployee & "'))"
Me.Employee_subform.Form.RecordSource = myFilter
Me.Employee_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

This works Fine, the problem is that I have now a combobox which contains more than one column in the combobox (see picture) [image]

If I use the Code above It doesn't work .. How should I adapt my vba code, so that it works when Filtering.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific abaout what "Doesn't" work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is in the combo's *After Update* event, you can adapt the `SELECT` to the combo value --- only add the `WHERE` clause when the combo value is not equal to *"(All)"*.

```vb
Private Sub ComboEmployee_AfterUpdate()
    Dim myFilter As String
    myFilter = "Select * from Filter_Employee"
    If Me.ComboEmployee.Value <> "(ALL)" Then
        myFilter = myFilter & " where [LastName] = '" & Me.ComboEmployee.Value & "'"
    End If
    Debug.Print myFilter '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
    Me.Employee_subform.Form.RecordSource = myFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @HansUp ,so my    code looks like this     `Private Sub Combo11_AfterUpdate()
Dim myFilter As String
myFilter = "Select * from Employee_ComboBox" & _
    " where Forms!Employee_subform!Combo11 = '(All)'" & _
    " Or [LastName] = Forms!Employee_subform!Combo11"
Debug.Print myFilter '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
Me.Employee_subform.Form.RecordSource = myFilter
End Sub`   But I get prompted to "Enter Parmeter Value for Forms!Employee_subform!Combo11" .. any Ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: If the combo is on a subform, you must reference it via its parent form (the form which contains the subform) ... like this pattern: `Forms!ParentForm!SubformControl!ComboName`  However, I will add a different approach to the answer because I suspect it will be easier.

Comment: It worked , I found out what I was doing wrong.. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry I didn't spot the simpler way sooner.  <head whack>

Comment: :Hi man, sorry to bother you again.Filter works just Fine in the Form that I created. But Now that I linked my form in a navigation Form , it doesn't work .. i receive the "Enter Parameter Value - Forms!Employee_form!Combo11" Code:     `Private Sub Combo11_AfterUpdate()
Dim myFilter As String
myFilter = "Select * from Filter_Employee" & _
    " where Forms!Employee_Form!Combo11 = '(All)'" & _
    " Or [LastName] = Forms!Employee_Form!Combo11"
Debug.Print myFilter '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
Me.Employee_subform.Form.RecordSource = myFilter
End Sub`

Comment: Never mind, I used the second solution u gave me ,and it worked .. I didn't initially use it because it didn't work for the "All" value, but the problem was ,that this is case sensitive..I didn't see you wrote ALL instead of All .. now everthing works fine.THanks again.